# Why can't I access the first element of a mutableListOf(object) in a function

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I changed List for MutableList<List<Restaurant?>>
and now restaurantList[0] shows an error type mismatch. But the variable main takes an object of type restaurant and restaurantList[0] is the first item of a list of restaurant objects so doesn't it work. It worked before the change to mutableList?

Error:
Type mismatch
required: Restaurant?
found: List<Restaurant?>

And I changed from  List to MutableList<List>

```
@Composable
fun ComposeMapDemo(restaurantList: MutableList<List<Restaurant?>>, navController: NavController){
    var main by remember{ mutableStateOf<Restaurant?>(null) }
        }
    if (restaurantList.isNotEmpty()){
        main = restaurantList[0]
    }
```

Comment: Please show the exact error message

Comment: You changed from `List<List<Restaurant?>>` to `MutableList<List<Restaurant?>>`, or did you change from just a `List<Restaurant?>`.  What you have now is a list of lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel that the problem is in type-checking. You have a state (`main`) that holds the `Restaurant?` type, and your first element in `restaurantList: MutableList<List<Restaurant?>>` is a `List<Restaurant>`. It seems like you need to replace `restaurantList: MutableList<List<Restaurant?>>` with `restaurantList: MutableList<Restaurant?>`.

Comment: I can't because the data that is passed in the function demands MutableList<List<Restaurant?>>

Comment: Then you probably need to figure out what that means -- why is it passing a list of lists?  What are the different lists of restaurants supposed to mean?  Once you can answer that question, you'll know how to get the single restaurant you want.